# Doing all my validation in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

How can I *stop* the UI layer from performing its conversion validation, or at least have it continue on?  If I have a textbox bound to a DateTime:

```
// view
<TextBox x:Name="StartTimeTextBox">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="StartTime"
                     StringFormat="t"
                     NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                     ValidatesOnExceptions="True" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <va:AlwaysSucceedsValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

// view model
[MyValidationAttribute]
public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
```

When the user selects all the text text in the textbox and deletes it (or types in "asdf"), the conversion fails, it gets a red border and validation *stops*.  I've tried using ValidatesOn... attributes (which I thought would allow my "`MyValidationAttribute`" to execute) without success.  I've also tried adding a ValidationRule that always returns true no matter what the `Text` - but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind `TextBox.Text` to a `DateTime`, and the user types in `"my hovercraft is full of little lambs"`, what can the `Binding` possibly assign to your viewmodel property for you to validate? There's nothing it can do.

You can set `Validation.ErrorTemplate` for the `TextBox` to an empty template, and that'll get rid of the red outline business, but you still won't get anything validatable in your viewmodel property.

If you want to validate string input from the user as a valid or invalid date, you're going to have to do that at some point where you have the raw string input in your hands.

If you want to do it in your viewmodel, that means giving your viewmodel a *string* property for `StartTime`, and binding that to the `TextBox`. Call it `StringStartTime`; in its setter, if the string is valid it sets `DateTime StartTime`; if not valid, it leaves `StartTime` alone but sets some error property, or throws an exception, or whatever.

Comment: The lambs must've eaten the eels - eww.  I thought that setting my own `ValidationRule` would override any defaults - is that not true?

Comment: @ScottSEA I'm trying it and I'm getting my Validate method invoked, and the garbage text I typed is in the `value` parameter. Then I return new `ValidationResult(true, null)`, and it gives me the red error border (or nothing if I set `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"` in XAML), and leaves my garbage text in the textbox. So when you say "validation stops", you mean it doesn't validate the next field in the UI?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't proceed to the ViewModel's Validation.  That's where I want it all to occur, because I've got a "Summary" `TextBlock` that displays the errors.  If validation stops at the UI, I can't display the validation message from the ViewModel... if that makes sense.

Comment: @ScottSEA Ah, I get it. Well yes, it can't proceed in that case because it doesn't have any DateTime value to assign to the viewmodel's property. Can't get there from here. If you want your viewmodel to take over parsing the string, you'd have to do something like the string property/datetime property hack I described. Or you could sacrifice that requirement and write validation rules that provide all the error messages for unparseable stuff like "asdf" for a DateTime.